# how to return true or false when a string contains any letters A-Z or a-z?

Tags: ruby

I am familiar with how to check if a string contains a substring, and also familiar with how to check if a single letter is a number or a letter, but how would I go about checking a string for any letters?

```
def letters?(string)
  # what do i do here?
end

# string could be anything from '111' to '1A2' to 'AB2589A5' etc...

string = '1A2C35'
if letters?(string) == true
  # do something if string has letters
else
  # do something else if it doesnt
end
```

Comment: It sounds like a good use-case for a regular expression.

Comment: `if string =~ /[A-Za-z]/` no need for an additional method [Example](http://rubular.com/r/XsGjPdDste)

Comment: that returns the first letter of the string

Comment: @alilland yes which is a truthy value. If there are no numbers it will return nil which is a falsey value. thus the conditional will work exactly as expected. If you would like to be explicit about a boolean then `string =~ /[A-Za-z]/ ? true : false` will do so.

Comment: @engineersmnky I drink “Moët,” my chief’s surname is “Kõhl,” I love Barça and I wonder what letter means :)

Comment: @mudasobwa well put. Although I read descriptions, I make assumptions and my ignorance to all else protects my comments from the perils of a poorly worded question. (Also I'm from 'Merica) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you can try something like it:

```
def letters?(string)
   string.chars.any? { |char| ('a'..'z').include? char.downcase }
end
```

If you don't wanna use regexp. This method return `true` if there are any letters in the string:

```
> letters? 'asd'
 => true 
> letters? 'asd123'
 => true 
> letters? '123'
 => false
```

Comment: `letters? 'привет'` according to Merriam Webster dictionary should return `true`, btw.

Comment: @mudasobwa, @alilland asked for method that should return `true`  or `false` after check string for any letter, I think language - is optional.

Comment: “ñ” is a letter by all means.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes your right, your method better, I'll remember it for future)

Comment: @mudasobwa technically Merriam Webster also states [This is a Letter](https://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_large/public/thumbnails/image/2014/07/17/10/cleese.JPG)  :)

Comment: @engineersmnky this letter must have `cover` method amongst `upcase` and `downcase` :)

Answer (score 6):

The proper way to check if the string contains any letter, is to use [`\p{L}`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) matcher. That way you’ll match

```
"ï" # in "naĩve"
```

as well as

```
"ç" # in Barça
```

The code would be:

```
def letters? string
  !string[/\p{L}/].nil?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This code checks if there are any letters from A to Z, the upper and lower case using regexp. If they are, it return true, false otherwise. This syntax a simple if else statement.

```
def letters?
    self.match(/[A-Za-z]/) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I made my answer a little bit more wider.

Answer (score -2):

```
  def letters?(string)
    if (string =~ /[A-Za-z]/).to_s.length > 0
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

Comment: What is `self` for?!

Comment: had it in a module when i tested it, fixed :)

Comment: This answer is wrong (besides it is ugly and not ruby idiomatic.)